# How do I use lastpass on Safari for macOS Big Sur?

Tags: safari, password, big-sur

The docs on lastpass did not help.

I installed lastpass app, but no lastpass behaviour shows up in safari.

Answer (score 1):

[Last Pass Help](https://twitter.com/LastPassHelp/status/1327393767968575488?s=20) recommends installing version 4.6 for macOS Big Sur from their [direct download site](https://lastpass.com/misc_download2.php) instead of the app store version.

If you're still having issues, [Last Pass support forum](https://community.logmein.com/t5/Support-Discussions/macOS-Big-Sur-Safari-14-0-1-Official-Support/m-p/256589#M25321) recommends uninstalling the app, the safari extension, emptying trash and rebooting your mac and then reinstalling from their direct download site.